# Pythons webbrowser.open_new_tab(url) with proxy

Tags: python, proxy, python-webbrowser

I have a proxy setup on my machine (Win -7).
I have written a  python program which tries to open new tab of a browser with given URL, with the help of `webbrowser` module in python.

But `webbrowser.open_new_tab(URL)` fails when I check the "Use proxy server for your LAN" checkbox in Internet Explorer settings (under LAN Settings), but it works perfectly fine when I uncheck this box .

I don't understand why this is happening. Is there any way by which the `webbroser` module works with a proxy?
Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: If you check "use proxy...", don't you have to define one?

Comment: Its defined. Everything works fine except webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)

Comment: could this be of help to evade the proxy settings: http://codereview.games1234.net/view/63538899237321009833419/proxy-evasion-browser-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the noise.

I just realized that urllib2.urlopen(url) was breaking the things, not webbrowser.open_new_tab(url).

We need to use proxyhandlers of urllib2 to get away with this.

@Lawrence, Thanks for the help